# Java android set color setFastScroll

Tags: java, android

I want to change a colour f fasr scroll on listView , now I have a white and I want to change color. I did this :

```
listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
listView.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/your_custom_drawable_color</item>
```

Comment: And where I should add this styles.xml

Comment: You will find the existing styles.xml in res -> values -> styles.xml. Just add the second item from the above code. AppTheme will already be there.